# Jackson set element name depending on generic type

Tags: java, xml, generics, jackson

Is it possible, using jackson, to set the name of an element depending on the class of a generic?

Given the following scenario:

```
public class Room<T> {
    private int roomId;
    private String roomName;
    private T roomDetails;
//constructor getters, setters
}

public class Livingroom {
    private boolean hasCouch;
    private int numOfSeats;
//constructor getters, setters
}

public class Bathroom{
    private boolean hasShower;
    private boolean hasSink;
//constructor getters, setters
}
```

If I use jackson to serialize the room object (with livingroom set as the generic), it looks like this:

```
public void jackson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Livingroom livingroom = new Livingroom();
    livingroom.setHasCouch(true);
    livingroom.setNumOfSeats(5);

    Room<Livingroom> room = new Room<>();
    room.setRoomDetails(livingroom);
    room.setRoomId(10);
    room.setRoomName("MyRoom");
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(room);
    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

With the result being:

```
<Room>
    <roomId>10</roomId>
    <roomName>MyRoom</roomName>
    <roomDetails>
        <hasCouch>true</hasCouch>
        <numOfSeats>5</numOfSeats>
    </roomDetails>
</Room>
```

What I would like the result to look however is:

```
<Room>
    <roomId>10</roomId>
    <roomName>MyRoom</roomName>
    <Livingroom>
        <hasCouch>true</hasCouch>
        <numOfSeats>5</numOfSeats>
    </Livingroom>
</Room>
```

And vice versa for the Bathroom or all other possible rooms. Is it possible to let jackson derive the element name from the actual class of the generic at runtime?

Comment: i can't imagine how that could work since once the classes are compiled, the "generic" information is effectively gone (it's only there for compile checking).  you "could" write a object mapper factory that, when serializing that field, does the runtime check of the class and modifies the exported xml tagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the element name depending on the generic type with a **custom serializer**.

Keep in mind that jackson uses the `get` methods to name the properties of the serialized json/xml, that is why you are getting the element `roomDetails` on your serialized xml.

Annotations like `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonProperty` expect a constant value so they cannot be used in this case because we can just determine the type at runtime.

**Solution:**

`Room` class annotated with `@JsonSerialize`:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = RoomSerializer.class)
public class Room<T> {
    private int roomId;
    private String roomName;
    private T roomDetails;

    public int getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomId(int roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    public String getRoomName() {
        return roomName;
    }

    public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
    }

    public T getRoomDetails() {
        return roomDetails;
    }

    public void setRoomDetails(T roomDetails) {
        this.roomDetails = roomDetails;
    }
}
```

Classes like `Bathroom` and `Livingroom` remain unaltered.

`RoomSerializer` implementation:

```
public class RoomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Room> {

    public RoomSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public RoomSerializer(Class<Room> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Room value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("roomId", value.getRoomId());
        jgen.writeStringField("roomName", value.getRoomName());

        // Here we determine the field name depending on the type
        String roomDetailsFieldName = value.getRoomDetails().getClass().getSimpleName();
        jgen.writeObjectField(roomDetailsFieldName, value.getRoomDetails());

        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And with your example you will get what you desire:

```
<Room>
    <roomId>10</roomId>
    <roomName>MyRoom</roomName>
    <Livingroom>
        <hasCouch>true</hasCouch>
        <numOfSeats>5</numOfSeats>
    </Livingroom>
</Room>
```